# Activities to avoid big query warm-up occurence

Tags: google-bigquery

On the streaming data article, it is mentioned "After several hours of inactivity, the warm-up period will occur again during the next insert."
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

What are those activities that can keep the connection warm?
I'll be writing connection pool and it is expected to provide bigquery object that can put data in without any warm up period.

Answer (score 1):

The data goes in whether it's warming up or not. It's only added to a queue to get inserted into BQ after the instance is brought back to action. The docs say that takes two minutes. So you can insert without worries, but can't query that specific data in the first two minutes. If you need it active constantly, any activity will keep the instance running, so you can then just schedule a cron to do a very very small read on the hour. (I'm not sure if reading from saved table results will keep the instance alive, most probably not; but I'm not certain. Same for cached results.)

I don't think it's such a big concern to worry about it. Normally with streaming data you don't have long hours of complete inactivity. If so, you can consider just doing normal batch jobs.

Comment: It is a concern and that data should be available as soon as it arrives. At service startup, I will spin off the objects and then need to keep it active. The question is that what those activities referred in the article are?

Comment: I will have certain number of available connections as a buffer. Ex; there could be 10 write threads utilizing one connection each at any point in time, but I want to have 3 additional connections kept warm  to handle spikes in the threads and get their data readable instantly. When there are  13 treads writing, there should be again 3 additional one.

Comment: @East2West Remember it's not a stream socket connection, it's just a lot of tcp requests making the flow look like a stream. Having 3 additional connections kept warm doesn't make sense as it's not possible. Only your BQ instance needs to remain 'active/warm' to prevent the 2min warmup/startup. That can easily be done by just making your instance use 1 cpu cycle, e.g. any type of (uncached) query. Outside the instance loading warmup: data is always instantly available and you can even then look at table decorators to narrow your results to recent inserts.

Answer (score 1):

The warmup period discussed in the streaming documentation is related to whether recently streamed records to a table are made visible to queries, not whether the table will accept streaming records immediately.  If a table is new or hasn't been receiving records via streaming for hours, then it may take up to 2 minutes before these freshly streamed records are scanned when generating query results.

Unless your usage pattern is to only stream records every few hours and then immediately query, this should not be a concern.  Even a small number of streaming records per hour is enough to keep the table "warmed up" in this context.