# Successful Dataflow Pipeline being run multiple times via PythonVirtualenvOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam

I am running an Apache Beam pipeline (deployed with Google Dataflow) which is being orchestrated with Apache Airflow.

The DAG file looks like the following:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonVirtualenvOperator

import custom_py_file #beam job in this file 


default_args = {
    'owner': 'name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
    'email': ['email@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

CONNECTION_ID = 'proj'

with DAG('dag_pipeline', schedule_interval='@once', template_searchpath=['/home/airflow/gcs/dags/'], max_active_runs=15, catchup=True, default_args=default_args) as dag:


    lines = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='lines',
        python_callable=custom_py_file.main, #this file has a function main() where the beam job is declared 
        requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]', 'pandas'],
        python_version=3,
        dag=dag
    )

lines
```

The beam pipeline file (`custom_py_file.py`) is as follows:

```py
def main():
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
    import argparse
    import time


    class ETL(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, row):
            #process data 

    def run(argv=None):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument(
            '--input',
            dest='input',
            default='gs://bucket/input/input.txt',
            help='Input file to process.'
            )
        known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
        pipeline_args.extend([
              '--runner=DataflowRunner',
              '--project=proj',
              '--region=region',
              '--staging_location=gs://bucket/staging/',
              '--temp_location=gs://bucket/temp/',
              '--job_name=name-{}'.format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d%h%M%s").lower()),
              '--setup_file=/home/airflow/gcs/dags/setup.py',
              '--disk_size_gb=350',
              '--machine_type=n1-highmem-96',
              '--num_workers=24',
              '--autoscaling_algorithm=NONE'
              ]) 

        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
        pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
            rows = (p | 'read rows' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input))
            etl = (rows | 'process data' >> beam.ParDo(ETL()))

        p.run().wait_until_finish()

    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    run()
```

I am using a [`PythonVirtualenvOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L201) because I cannot use Python3 and a `BashOperator` with my current version of airflow (Version : 1.10.2-composer), and I need Python3 to run this pipeline.

The problem is that despite a successful run, Airflow submits another Dataflow Job. Note that this is NOT a retry, as the logs show that it is all "one" task run. However the Dataflow logs show it running the exact same job again after it has already run successful once.

[image: dataflow logs]

What is going on here? Is the successful dataflow job not outputting a 0 value? How do I get it to move on to the next task if it ran correctly? Thanks!

Comment: How do you run the pipeline in your python code? Can something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52282001/6121516) be happening?

Comment: I updated the question to include my beam file @GuillemXercavins

Comment: Yes I think that might be it, I will change it and try it again, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it's not considered a retry and one job executes after the first one ends made me suspect of something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52282001/6121516). Checking your Python code I see that you call both `with beam.Pipeline()` and `p.run()`:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    rows = (p | 'read rows' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input))
    etl = (rows | 'process data' >> beam.ParDo(ETL()))

p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

This will trigger two consecutive executions. You can do either option (but not both):

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    rows = (p | 'read rows' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input))
    etl = (rows | 'process data' >> beam.ParDo(ETL()))
```

---

```py
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

rows = (p | 'read rows' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input))
etl = (rows | 'process data' >> beam.ParDo(ETL()))

p.run().wait_until_finish()
```